# Three20 TTMessageController lite alternative

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

Looking for TTMessageController (specifically the TTPickerTextField) lite weight alternative? Without the complete importing of the Three20 sources:(

MFMailComposeViewController is not a good alternative as I would like only have the Picker on a customized view.

Comment: Implementing Three20 isn't that hard? Why not take the 5 minutes to do it?

Comment: I think he's looking for a lite alternative, as importing the three20 framework usually adds around 20mb to the app.

Comment: Rocky you are right - LITE is key - i will look into you suggestion below but from looking at the code I see so much dependency that I just went to writing the component from scratch will share with community once done.

Comment: @Gil Margolin check out Jeffs new framework Nimbus (Three20 but done properly). Its not released yet officially but it looks more modular, less complex and lightweight. http://jverkoey.github.com/nimbus/index.html

Comment: thanks rocky put it as an answer and i will accept it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to my comment above, the whole three20 app will add around 20mb to your app, however the latest versions of Three20 are modular, meaning you can choose which parts of Three20 you want to use in your app. You just need to specify what module you need in the Python script.

Jeff does a good job of explaining it over on three20.info and has a good youtube demonstration as well.

http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project